# Merge multiple rasa stories without using forms

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I have an intent as below which will fetch vaccination details from the database. this intent requires two slots(country, vaccine) to be filled, if no slots or at least one slot is filled, I am using different stories to ask the user to fill the slots, then it will show vaccination details at last.

I am using rasa: 1.10.2 for this chatbot.

```
## intent:vaccination_details
- get vaccination details from [USA](country) for [Covishield](vaccine)
- show vaccination details
- show me [Covishield](vaccine) vaccination details in [USA](country)
- get vaccination details from [USA](country)
- show [Covishield](vaccine) vaccination details
```

I am using the following stories to fill the slots, here **action_select_vaccine** and **action_select_country** are custom actions that fetch a list of available vaccines and country lists from the database as buttons for the user to select.

Since it requires only two slots to be filled from actions, I am not using RASA forms. Can we merge these stories into one or two without using forms?

```
## Story_1: vaccine,country not given
* vaccination_details
    - action_select_vaccine
* select_vaccine{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - slot{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - action_select_country
* select_country{"country":"USA"}
    - slot{"country":"USA"}
    - action_vaccination_details
    
## Story_2: country not given
* vaccination_details{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - slot{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - action_select_country
* select_country{"country":"USA"}
    - slot{"country":"USA"}
    - action_vaccination_details

## Story_3: vaccine not given
* vaccination_details{"country":"USA"}
    - slot{"country":"USA"}
    - action_select_vaccine
* select_vaccine{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - slot{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - action_vaccination_details
    
## Story_4: vaccine,country given
* vaccination_details{"country":"USA","vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - slot{"country":"USA"}
    - slot{"vaccine":"Covishield"}
    - action_vaccination_details
```

Comment: Hi @harishd - the stories represent your training data for training a dialogue manager (i.e. the machine learning component that learns to select the next best action for the bot, given the current dialogue). Could you clarify why you would like to merge any of your stories in your question?

Comment: if in future, if i need 2 or 3 more slots(region, state and city) to be filled from the user, i will need to create more stories to ask user to fill the empty slots. if intent is raised with region, country, vaccine then user should be prompted to fill unfilled slots(state, city) and if region, vaccine is provided in intent, it should ask for country, state and city likewise.

Comment: if no of slots required is 5, i might have to create 2^5=32 stories.

Comment: you might need a lot more than these. the `core` model learns from the example stories you train it on. for example it might learn that it should ask for the country after it has asked for the vaccine. the more examples it sees, the better the policy will be learnt.

if you have a mix of mandatory and optional slots, I'd recommend focusing on the mandatory ones in the stories first (by pro-actively querying them from the user). after that, you can ask for the optional ones.

Comment: OK, got it. thanks.